# Configure Ninject to Resolve null when using ToMethod

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject

How can I configure Ninject to resolve `null` with my constructor injection? I am using `ToMethod` with a factory method and `InTransientScope`. My factory is designed to return `null` if certain things are not met. However, Ninject throws an exception which forces me to use a parameterless constructor, which I would like to avoid.

I am binding this way:

```
Bind<IClient>
    .ToMethod(x => someFactoryMethod())
    .InTransientScope();
```

`someFactoryMethod()` may return `IClient` or `null`.

I would like the injected class to get the `null` passed in instead of the exception. When I use `TryGet`, I get `null` on my injected class when I try to resolve it.

I am using the latest Ninject for .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Prevent using `null` as a special case. Try using the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) instead. This prevents you from having to polute your code base with null checks:

```
Bind<IClient>
    .ToMethod(x => someFactoryMethod() ?? NullClient.Instance)
    .InTransientScope();

// Null Object implementation of IClient
public class NullClient : IClient
{
    public static readonly IClient Instance = new NullClient();

    // Implement the members of IClient to do nothing.
    public void ClientOperation()
    {
        // noop.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

You have to configure that null is allowed. I have no source code at hand at the moment but it should be something like the following:

```
new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings { AllowNullInjection = true });
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can specify this just on my call to `Bind`?

Answer (score 2):

You can mark your constructor with the `Optional` attribute.

Comment: I don't want to decorate my classes with Ninject attributes.